# How to convert nginx configuration to ingress kubernetes yaml configuration?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I deployed Vue JS on kubernetes. And I need to configure nginx route like on this page :

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

The configuration is like this :

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

How to convert that configuration to ingress kubernetes yaml configuration?

I tried this but doesn't work

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /index.html
  name: backoffice
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/backoffice
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev.abc.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: backoffice-svc
              servicePort: 443
            path: /
```

And I tried with this annotation and still doesn't work :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /app1
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

The [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) might look like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-nice-server
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "some.nice.server.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something1/?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: something-1
          servicePort: 8080
```

This is nicely explained in [Kubernetes Ingress-Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md#rewrite) dosc.

Or, you might also use [Configuration snippet](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet) in Annotations:

```
...
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
...
```

Comment: Be careful when using configuration-snippet. Making configuration-snippet will add nginx config to ingress controller and can bring the **entire nginx** (not only your service) down if not configured correctly.

Comment: the second option throws an error location is not present .

Comment: try_files is useful in custom config file while making docker image from nginx and add this file into it...this helped me in my scenario with some twist! up vote

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, I had the same situation as your that I encountered today.  As nginx ingress controller is in another isolated pod, the generated nginx rules in nginx ingress controller can't detect files and resources on your services. It just forward the requests to your services. The proper location to put the try_files directive should be in the your service's pods.

My working case is as following:
there is a nginx container in my service pod, I put "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; " in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Answer (score 0):

The best way that works for me was to update my docker file to load a custom nginx.conf with the follow setup:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;

  gzip on;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    #Vue router configuration
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
        index index.html;
    }
    location @router {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
    }
  }
}
```

After that I just changed my docker file to load this nginx.conf as the code above:

```
# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage

# Copy the custom nginx configuration file to the container
COPY infrastructure/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80 for the application
EXPOSE 80

# Start the application when the container starts
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then just deploy your image that it should work fine without touching on your ingress.